# Changing the Freight Tax Category in Sales order screen is not re- calculating the freight tax

Tags: acumatica

I am changing Freight tax category pragmatically based on the tax category of the item selected in the detail tab

```
protected virtual void SOOrder_CustomerLocationID_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e, PXFieldUpdated del)
    {
        if (del != null)
            del(sender, e);
        var row = (SOOrder)e.Row;
        Location location = PXSelect<Location, Where<Location.locationID, Equal<Required<Location.locationID>>>>.Select(Base, Base.Document.Current.CustomerLocationID);
        if (location != null)
        {
            string custtaxzone = location.CTaxZoneID;
            bool taxableitem = false;
            if (custtaxzone == "TAXABLE")
            {
                foreach (SOLine line in Base.Transactions.Select())
                {
                    if (line.TaxCategoryID == "PATAX")
                    {
                        taxableitem = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (taxableitem)
                    Base.Document.Current.FreightTaxCategoryID = "PATAX";
                else
                    Base.Document.Current.FreightTaxCategoryID = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

The value is properly updating but the freight tax is not calculating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In RowUpdated event, update the DataView after changing the value and invoke calculation of the tax attribute:

```
public void SOOrder_RowUpdated(PXCache sender, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
   SOOrder row = e.Row as SOOrder;

   if (!sender.ObjectsEqual<SOOrder.customerLocationID, SOOrder.customerLocationID>(e.OldRow, e.Row))
   {        
      Base.Document.Current.FreightTaxCategoryID = "PATAX";
      Base.Document.Update(Document.Current);
      SOOrderTaxAttribute.Calculate<SOOrder.freightTaxCategoryID>(sender, e);
   }
}
```

Invoke the Default attribute to clear the freight tax:

```
Base.Document.Current.FreightTaxCategoryID = null;
Base.Document.Update(Document.Current);
sender.SetDefaultExt<SOOrder.freightTaxCategoryID>(e.Row);
```